# How to map entity properties to dto in EF Core 7

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-7.0

I tried so many times and I can't map my entity to dto in the select statement and it gives me the following error.

> Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable1[PrjOnlineStore.Core.Domain.Products.ProductDto]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable1[PrjOnlineStore.Core.Domain.Products.Entities.TblProducts]'.

Here is my code:

```
[HttpGet("GetProductDetailsByProductID")]
public IActionResult GetProductDetailsByProductID(int? ProductID)
{
    if (ProductID == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    var GetProduct = _Context.TblProducts.AsQueryable();

    var GetAllProductsVariant = _Context.TblProductVariants
                             .Where(x => x.RefProductID == ProductID)
                             .AsEnumerable();

    var GetAllProductDetails = _Context.TblProductDetails
                            .Where(x => x.RefProductID == ProductID);

    foreach (var item in GetAllProductsVariant)
        GetProduct = (IQueryable<TblProducts>)GetProduct
                             .Where(x => x.ProductID == ProductID &&
                                    x.ProductVariants.Any(y => 
                                        y.RefProductID == ProductID.Value))
                            .Select(x => new ProductDto {
                               ID = x.ProductID,
                               Name = x.Title,
                               Price = x.Price
                    }).Distinct();

    foreach (var item in GetAllProductDetails)
        GetProduct = GetProduct.Where(x => x.ProductID == ProductID
                                   && x.ProductDetails.Any(y => y.RefProductID == item.RefProductID));

    return Ok(GetProduct);
}
```

Here is my model:

```
[Table("TblProducts")]
public class TblProducts
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? Title { get; set; }

    public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public long Visit { get; set; }

    public bool IsAvaiable { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsSendImmediate { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsAvailableAtStore { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    [NotMapped]
    public string? ProductRate { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string? ProductColor { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    [NotMapped]
    public string? ProductImage { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    [NotMapped]
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    [NotMapped]
    public string? Tags { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsOriginal { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    [Required]
    public string? ProductType { get; set; }

    public long CategoryID { get; set; }

    public long BrandID { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual TblCategory Categorys { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual TblBrands Brands { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [ForeignKey("RefProductID")]
    public virtual ICollection<TblOrders>? Orders { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("RefProductID")]
    public virtual ICollection<TblProductDetails> ProductDetails { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("RefProductID")]
    public virtual ICollection<TblProductVariants> ProductVariants { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Post the full method. The error complains that you tried to return an `IQueryable<ProductDto>` when an `IQueryable<TblProducts>` was expected. If `GetProduct` is an `IQueryable<TblProducts>`  you can't assign an `IQueryable<ProductDto>` to it.

Comment: Are you trying to construct the query dynamically? You can keep using the same query variable only as long as you return the *same* type, eg after appending another `Where`. You can't use it if you modify the query type. Neither the loop nor the `Select` clause make a lot of sense here as `item` isn't used anywhere.

Comment: What is the type of `GetProduct`? I assume it's `IQueryable<TblProducts>`. Your `Select()` returns `IQueryable<ProductDto>` so you cannot assign it to `GetProduct` again. Even with casting.

Comment: I guess if you post the models and tell what the result should be you get a better answer for your needs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos here is full details of my entity and full method.thank you.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos and yes I want tot construct the query dynamic.

Comment: The code doesn't make much sense. The loop won't compile but even if it did, all conditions would be true. The `GetAllProductsVariant` and `GetAllProductDetails` queries contain the target product's details. EF will load them again when the query runs. You could replace all this code with `var products= await _context.Products.Include(x=>x.Variants).Include(x=>x.Details).Where(x=>x.Id=ProductID).ToListAsync(); return Ok(products);`

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride yes you're right the GetProduct type is Iqueryable<TblProducts> and when I try to put it's properties it gives me above error.

Comment: Please adapt your code according to the comments/corrections above. Remove the loop `foreach (var item in GetAllProductsVariant)` because it's useless as stated above. Then you can remove `GetAllProductsVariant` because it's not used. Also remove `GetAllProductDetails` and query the products using `Where(x => x.RefProductID == ProductID && x.ProductDetails.Any())`. Then all that's left is `var GetProduct = _Context.TblProducts.Where(...).Select(x => new ProductDto { ...`.

Comment: @GertArnold I remove both loops from my code and it works as you said before.thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Model TblProducts already has collections for ProductVariants and ProductDetails you can include them in the query.

```
 var productsWithVariantsAndDetails = _Context.TblProducts
    .Include(x => x.ProductVariants)
    .Include(x => x.ProductDetails)
    .Where(x => x.ProductID == ProductID)   
    .Distinct();
```

You could directly put them into the DTO but for now there would be no reason to do this beacause you discard the information from the variants and details objects.

```
var productsWithVariantsAndDetails = _Context.TblProducts
    .Include(x => x.ProductVariants)
    .Include(x => x.ProductDetails)
    .Where(x => x.ProductID == ProductID)
    .Select(x => new ProductDto {
        ID = x.ProductID,
        Name = x.Title,
        Price = x.Price
    })
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: I try your solution but it give the same error.

Comment: Maybe rebuild or the error is from some other code?  I don't think it is possible that the error comes from this code. Confirm does var x = _Context.TblProducts.ToList() work ? 
Then does _Context.TblProducts .Where(x => x.ProductID == ProductID).ToList() work ?
This way you can make the problem smaller.

Comment: I did all of this but when I add select method to query it gives me that error and it's ok your answer but it's not work for this because EF could not cast the Queryable entities to linq methods.

Comment: I think the problem is that I want to query product table over and over after foreach loop and somehow I have to change return type to ProductDTOs.

Comment: Its a long way to get jobs done :) that would be a use case for another question.

Comment: All these `Include`s are ignored because of the projection (`Select`).

Comment: @GertArnold So what is your suggest for solve this problem?

Comment: Well, see my comment above.